# Getting Project List from Visual Studio Online Rest API

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I am pulling project list from Visual Studio Online using Rest API.

I have done authentication with https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview

I am using https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/tfs/projects to get projects.

But I am not getting all projects. Like we have 118 projects. But I am getting 100-112 projects based on different user account.

Is there any project administration level that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried it using an account that is a member of "Project Collection Administrators" https://<youraccount>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security#_a=members

Comment: Yes, I am using username from that list. But I can't understand the difference in response.

Comment: @Mazhar, have you noticed the REST API returns top 100 projects by default? This can be changed, though. Perhaps, that's the reason you get not all of them?

Comment: What do you get when you type: "https ://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0&$top=120"